# How can I avoid breaking $ref without removing $id in my JSON Schema?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

The presence of the `$id` field in the following JSON Schema causes a `jsonschema.exceptions._WrappedReferencingError` when I try to call jsonschema.validate on it using the jsonref library in python.

```json
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "definitions": {
        "first_definition": {
          "value": "this is definitions/first_definition"
        },
        "second_definition": {
          "$id": "any_value",
          "properties": {
            "sections": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/first_definition"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "$ref": "#/definitions/second_definition"
    }
```

Apparently having an `$id` changes the scope that $ref can see? The $ref that fails is the `'/definitions/first_definition'` ref, and the WrappedReferencingError holds a referencing.exceptions.PointerToNowhere'. I can remove the `$id` to get rid of the error, but that seems like the wrong solution. Is there a way to still have an `$id`, but without breaking the $ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you need the `$id`? I'm just curious if you think there is use case you believe it solves.

The `$id` acts as a scoping mechanism. It's an identifier for a schema. Essentially, it's creating a new "file" of just that schema. so the use of `#/definitions/first_definition` means it's looking for the `first_definition` in the `any_value` schema root.

think of it like this..

##### root schema

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "first_definition": {
      "value": "this is definitions/first_definition"
    },
    "second_definition": {
      "$id": "any_value",
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/first_definition"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$ref": "#/definitions/second_definition"
}
```

##### `any_value` schema.

`first_definition` is not defined in this schema, so it doesn't resolve to anything, thus throws an error

```json
{
  "$id": "any_value",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "sections": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/first_definition"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {}
}
```

When you remove the `$id`, it changes the scope of the `#/definitions/...` to the root of the original schema, where it finds the definition for `first_definintion` defined.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "first_definition": {
      "value": "this is definitions/first_definition"
    },
    "second_definition": {
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/first_definition"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$ref": "#/definitions/second_definition"
}
```

If you really have your heart set on using `$id`, you need to give the root schema an id to reference. Then you can resolve the reference.

```json
{
  "$id": "root_schema",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "first_definition": {
      "value": "this is definitions/first_definition"
    },
    "second_definition": {
      "$id": "any_value",
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "$ref": "root_schema#/definitions/first_definition"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$ref": "#/definitions/second_definition"
}
```

An alternative to the id reference is to use relative or absolute file path references.

assume the file name is `root.schema.json`. This will resolve to the file path and the root of the schema becomes available with the `#` which allows you to navigate through the file.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "first_definition": {
      "value": "this is definitions/first_definition"
    },
    "second_definition": {
      "$id": "any_value",
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "$ref": "./root.schema.json#/definitions/first_definition"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$ref": "#/definitions/second_definition"
}
```